# Using Salesforce with a BlackBerry Z10

Tags: chatter, app, touch, blackberry

Following my research on the Internet, I noticed there's nothing much available for the **Z10** to access *Salesforce.com*. There's a version of **Salesforce Classic** and **Chatter** available for older devices, but nothing for the latest one. Also, **Salesforce Touch** seems to be only available for *iPad* in *iPhone*.

So I'm wondering Stackers, is there an application or a workaround available to access Salesforce on a **BlackBerry Z10**?

Comment: We are facing one strange issue, Blackberry users are not able to approve using email. Email approval is working for all other devices like iPhone, iPad and other mobile devices except Blackberry. Is it related to your question? can we solve this problem? Is it salesforce known issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as I know, theres no native app for blackberry's latest os.

That said, the api's are standards based, and the auth is standards based... You could become Salesforce Famous for building one! I'll volunteer to help with generic rest api/auth issues but i can't speak to blackberry os stuff.

That said, I think, *think* you can use the web interface with the new os.

Comment: With HTML5, of course, it could be possible. The only problem is that Salesforce Touch isn't accessible when your device isn't an iPad or iPhone. I guess Salesforce is looking for the browser used when a client is accessing it.

Comment: We are facing one strange issue, Blackberry users are not able to approve using email. Email approval is working for all other devices like iPhone, iPad and other mobile devices except Blackberry. Is it related to your question? can we solve this problem? Is it salesforce known issue?